# Не происходит вывод в Perl, пока я не введу переменную

Tags: perl

Имеется программа, читающая данные из файла и добавляющая их в массив:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use utf8;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use Switch;

open(FILE, "+<prodazhi.txt");
binmode FILE, ":utf8";
binmode STDOUT, ":utf8";
# здесь функции, работающие с массивом
while (<FILE>) {
    chomp;
    ($id, $name, $serial, $delivery, $amount, $cost, $date) = split '\t';
    add_new($id, $name, $serial, $delivery, $amount, $cost, $date);
}

print 'Выберите действие';
$_ = <STDIN>;
print $_;
```

(функция `add_new` добавляет данные в массив)

Нужно, чтобы после вывода строки "Выберите действие" я мог ввести номер действия для выполнения определённого действия с массивом. Однако строка не выводится до тех пор, пока я не совершу ввод. Т.е. я ввожу цифру "1", и только тогда он выводит "Введите действие1". До этого поток вывода как будто блокируется.

Подскажите, как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Perldoc / perlvar / autoflush](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24OUTPUT_AUTOFLUSH)

**$|**

> If set to nonzero, forces a flush right away and after every write or
>   print on the currently selected output channel.

То есть:

```
local $| = 1;
# ...
print 'Выберите действие: ';
```

Comment: И что делает этот код?

Comment: @Byulent, добавил ссылку на perldoc.